# Is there a way to check the latest uploaded videos in Youtube, in reverse chronological order?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to check the latest uploaded videos in Youtube, in reverse chronological order ?

Comment: yours or in general?

Comment: You can do `<search query> before:YYYY-MM-DD site:youtube.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. If you try to construct an [empty search query sorted by upload date](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=&search_sort=video_date_uploaded&uni=3), you get seemingly random results from the last few hours.

More than 48h of video are uploaded *every minute* on youtube ([source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/google/8536634/YouTube-users-uploading-two-days-of-video-every-minute.html)), so perhaps that's why they don't have a feature like that.